# bash script to remove previous backup

Tags: bash, shell

I set up a daily cron job to backup my server.

In my folder backup, the backup command generates 2 files : the archive itself .tar.gz and a file .info.json like the ones below:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1617 Feb  2 16:17 20200202-161647.info.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48699726 Feb  2 16:17 20200202-161647.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1617 Feb  3 06:25 20200203-062501.info.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48737781 Feb  3 06:25 20200203-062501.tar.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     1618 Feb  4 06:25 20200204-062501.info.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 48939569 Feb  4 06:25 20200204-062501.tar.gz
```

How to I write a bash script that will only keep the last 2 archives and deletes all the others backup (targ.gz and info.json).

In this example, that would mean deleted  20200204-062501.info.json and 20200204-062501.tar.gz .

Edit:

I replace -name by -wholename in the script but when I run it, it doesn't  have any effects apparently.The old archives are still there and they have not been deleted.

the script :

```
#!/bin/bash

DEBUG="";
DEBUG="echo DEBUG...";    #put last to safely debug without deleting files
keep=2;
for suffix in /home/archives .json .tar; do
    list=( $( find . -wholename "*$suffix" ) ); #allow for zero names
    if [ ${#list[@]} -gt $keep ]; then
        # delete all but last $keep oldest files
        ${DEBUG}rm -f "$( ls -tr "${list[@]}" | head -n-$keep )";
    fi
done
```

Edit 2:

if I run @sorin script, does it actually delete everything if I believe the script output?

The archive folder before running the script:

https://pastebin.com/7WtwVHCK

The script I run:

```
find home/archives/ \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -print0 |\
    sort -zr |\
    sed -z '3,$p' | \
    xargs -0 echo rm -f
```

The script output:

https://pastebin.com/zd7a2zcq

Edit 3 :

The command  `find /home/archives/ -daystart \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -mtime +1 -exec echo rm -f {} +` works and does the job.

Marked as solved

Comment: No,I mean to delete those 2 files.

Comment: if the files are generated daily then the simplest approach would be to use find ` find /home/archives/ -daystart \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;`

Comment: and if I run  find /home/archives/ -daystart ( -name '.json' -o -name '.tar.gz' ) -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \, I received the following error message:


./backup.sh: line 23: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./backup.sh: line 23: `find /home/archives/ -daystart ( -name '.json' -o -name '.tar.gz' ) -mtime +1 -exec echo rm -f {} \'

Comment: you have to escape the `(` and `)` ... `find /home/sorin/tmp/archives/ -daystart \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -mtime +1 -exec echo rm -f {} +` - this should work - remove the echo when you are ready, and play with +1 to if you want to keep more or less files

Comment: Perfect!!it's working now!Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is generated daily, a simple approach would be to take advantage of the -mtime find condition:

```
find /home/archives/ -daystart \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -mtime +1 -exec echo rm -f {} +
```

- `-daystart` - use the start of the day for comparing modification times
- `\( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \)` - select files that end either in `*.json` or `*.tar.gz`
- `-mtime +1` - modification time is older than 24 hours (from the day start)
- `-exec echo rm -f {} +` - remove the files (remove the `echo` after testing and verifying the result is what you want)

A simpler solution avoiding [ls and it's pitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and not depending on the modification time of the files:

```
find /home/archives/ \( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \) -print0 |\
    sort -zr |\
    sed -nz '3,$p' | \
    xargs -0 echo rm -f
```

- `\( -name '*.json' -o -name '*.tar.gz' \)` - find files that end in either `*.json` or `tar.gz`
- `-print0` - print them null separated
- `sort -zr` - `-z` tells `sort` to use null as a line separator, `-r` sorts them in reverse
- `sed  -nz '3,$p'` - `-z` same as above. `'3,$p'` - print lines between 3rd and the end (`$`)
- `xargs -0 echo rm -f` - execute rm with the piped arguments (remove the echo after you tested and you are satisfied with the command)

Note: not all `sort` and `sed` support the `-z` but most do. If you are stuck with such a situation, you might have to use a higher level language

Comment: sorry, forgot an -n at sed, fixed

Answer (score 0):

Find the two most recent files in path:

```
most_recent_json=$(ls -t *.json | head -1)
most_recent_tar_gz=$(ls -t *.tar.gz | head -1)
```

Remove everything else ignoring the found recent files:

```
rm -i $(ls -I $most_recent_json -I $most_recent_tar_gz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have fewer than 10 files and that they are created in pairs, then you can do something straightforward like this:

```
files_to_delete=$(ls -tr1 | tail -n+3)
rm $files_to_delete
```

The `-tr1` tells the [ls command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) to list the files in reverse chronological order by modification time, each on a single line.

The `tail -n+3` tells the [tail command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) to start at the third line (skipping the first two lines).

If you have more than 10 files, a more complicated solution will be necessary, or you would need to run this multiple times.

Comment: don't use back-ticks, use `$()`

Comment: Old habits.  I tend to write scripts that are backward compatible with Bourne Shell.  You make a good point, but they are equivalent and this is an example. However, OP did request bash, so I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic deleting can be hazardous to your mental state if it deletes unwanted files or aborts long scripts early due to unexpected errors. Say when there are fewer than 1+2 files in your example. Be sure the script does not fail if there are no files at all.

`tdir=/home/archives/;   #target dir
DEBUG="";
DEBUG="echo DEBUG...";    #put last to safely debug without deleting files
keep=2;
for suffix in .json .tar; do
    list=( $( find "$tdir" -name "*$suffix" ) ); #allow for zero names
    if [ ${#list[@]} -gt $keep ]; then
        # delete all but last $keep oldest files
        ${DEBUG}rm -f "$( ls -tr "${list[@]}" | head -n-$keep )";
    fi
done`

Comment: When I use this script, I receive the following warning :

find: warning: Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes (though pathnames do).  That means that '-name ‘*/home/archives/’' will probably evaluate to false all the time on this system.  You might find the '-wholename' test more useful, or perhaps '-samefile'.  

Alternatively, if you are using GNU grep, you could use 'find ... -print0 | grep -FzZ ‘*/home/archives/’'.

Comment: @qwerty1805  Interesting. Can you check the directory for a file with a name of '/' in it?
ls -l | grep '/' 
Every once in a blue moon I create such a file by accident.

Comment: My path in the script is "for suffix in /home/archives/ .json .tar; do"  . The output for ls -l | grep '/' is empty.

Comment: Edited command to add tdir=

Use of /home/... in for was killer.

Comment: it's working now wit the  tdir= Use of /home/ but the scrip deletes only the .json files .not the .tar.gz.I had to modify the lines "for suffix in .json .tar; do" to "for suffix in .json .tar.gz; do"  -  Thank you very much for the help

Comment: For some reasons, when I click on the top arrow to give you 1 point, the minus 1 is displayed and decrements the score  (( .It's still marked a zero. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: it seems it's working if I increment the score in the comments area .But not in the answer section.